# How to check the particular field in the firestore after authentication in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

- I have a field in firestore "isEnabled" it contains boolean value. So if it is equal to true then the user login to the app he prompted to the home page.
- If the field "isEnabled" is equal to false then a message should be displayed your account is disabled.
- For now I am able to do login and after that the field is checked and if it is false the user is logged out.
- Is there any way in which first authentication takes place, then the user is taken to a page where it shows "Checking few more details.." kind of a loading page and if the "isEnabled" field is false it will show your account has been disabled.
- I tried doing the checking of the field before but it's not possible and after

```
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
```

- As soon as the above line is executed the user is obviously prompted to the home page.
- What I am able to achieve that code is shown below -

```
Future signInWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      print(user.uid);
      final firestore = Firestore.instance;
      /*
      retrieving the fields from the database for checking the isEnabled field
       */
      await firestore.collection("admins").document(user.uid).get().then((resp) {
        logoutToast();
        if ((resp.data["isEnabled"]) == false) {
          disableToast();
          signOut();

        } else {
          loginToast();

        }
        return user;
      });
      //print(qn);
      //return user;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always disable a user in Firebase Auth and he won't be able to login at all.

If you still want to go your way and check a `isEnabled` on Firebase Firestore, than make the login and DON'T direct the user to the Home Screen, instead direct him to a Verification Screen and if `isEnabled` is `true` he goes to the Home Screen, if it's `false` you log him out.

Another solution is to have a Dialog shown in the Home Screen after the first time it's displayed and that Dialog will run the verification logic.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks !! I will be disabling the user from the application. I know you can disable the user by going to the firebase console.